# Get Android application lib directory

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, native, supercollider

I need to specify the location of some native libraries in my Android application.  I was accomplishing this with a hard-coded string:

```
public static final String DLL_DIR_STR = "/data/data/my.application.package/lib";
```

but wanted to get the path from Android instead.  Following posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105919/creating-directory-in-application-package-on-internal-storage), I used getDir() to find the lib directory, changing

```
superCollider = new SCAudio(DLL_DIR_STR);
```

to

```
superCollider = new SCAudio(container.$context().getDir("lib", 0).getAbsolutePath());
```

Oddly, the initial libraries seem to load correctly

```
Trying to load lib /data/data/my.application.package/lib/libsndfile.so 0x42718d80
Added shared lib /data/data/my.application.package/lib/libsndfile.so 0x42718d80
No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/my.application.package/lib/libsndfile.so 0x42718d80, skipping init
Trying to load lib /data/data/my.application.package/lib/libscsynth.so 0x42718d80
Added shared lib /data/data/my.application.package/lib/libscsynth.so 0x42718d80
```

But when libscsynth tries to load some additional code, it's using the wrong path:

```
OK, listing opendir(/data/data/my.application.package/app_lib)
```

Any ideas where the "app_" comes from?  I thought I must be using getDir() wrong, but the initial files load fine.  Could it be something in the native code?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You probably use **System.loadLibrary()** - this method knows where the app libraries are installed. On the contrary, **getDir()** _works hard_ to provide a directory that your app can safely use for file operations, so that it does not clash with special directories, of which **lib** is one example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, quite by accident, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603648/how-to-get-the-path-to-the-lib-folder-for-an-installed-package?answertab=votes#tab-top).  [ApplicationInfo.dataDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#dataDir) holds the location of the data directory, and "lib" is easily navigated to from there:

```
superCollider = new SCAudio(container.$context().getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/lib");
```

Alternatively, [nativeLibraryDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#nativeLibraryDir) takes you directly to the lib directory, but requires API level 9.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is no coincidence that **nativeLibraryDir** was introduced in Gingerbread. Before, the **lib** directory could be reliably found at **dataDir/../lib**, but since then apps can be installed on the external storage. Therefore, the recommended practice would be to check the API version and use **nativeLibraryDir** if available.

Answer (score 1):

`getDir` will always prepend app_  to the directory name so it is very odd that it is working the first time.  I would either just expect the app_ to be there or try using `getFilesDir`, at least you always know what it will return.  Does SuperCollider have a restriction on what the directory name is?

I found another [SuperCollider Project](https://github.com/glastonbridge/SuperCollider-Android/blob/master/src/net/sf/supercollider/android/ScService.java) that seems to be doing the same thing you did initially with the comment "*// TODO: not very extensible,*".. I found that funny :)

Comment: Thanks, I wondered if it was getDir().  "/lib" is the conventional location for native libraries; I think it's possible to change it; fortunately there's a good way to find "lib."