# Using openssl with FFmpeg on Android with NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, openssl

I cross compiled FFmpeg with openssl support using the [scripts](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android) from the Guardian project however my code crashes whenever I execute the following:

```
System.loadLibrary("crypto");    // loads OK
System.loadLibrary("ssl");       // loads OK
System.loadLibrary("avformat");  // crashes
```

The error:

```
dlopen("/data/data/wseemann.media.demo/lib/libavformat.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "SSL_library_init" referenced by "libavformat.so"...
```

I build libavformat with a toolchain and then run ndk-build using the following Android.mk file to create the .so files:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libswscale
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/$(LOCAL_MODULE).so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/$(LOCAL_MODULE).so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavformat
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/$(LOCAL_MODULE).so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavutil
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/$(LOCAL_MODULE).so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
```

It would seem that libavformat needs libcrypto and libssl when it is loaded but it can't find them or isn't loading them. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there normally is `libssl.so` in `/system/lib`. The loader [System.loadLibrary()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)) prefers that path to your app lib directory (`/data/data/your.package.name/lib`), and this is what may cause confusion. The easiest fix is to use [System.load("/data/data/your.package.name/lib/libssl.so")](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String)) instead (there are [correct ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645818/get-android-application-lib-directory) to obtain the path, too).

Another fix could be to rename `libssl.so` that you prepared, to `libavssl.so`, and call `System.loadLibrary("avssl")`. Note that *maybe* you will be required to recompile `libavformat` so that it looks for `libavssl.so`.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the feedback. However, I don't think the issue is with the call to System.loadLibrary("ssl") because I see the library being loaded in the log output and typically this command would fail of the specified library isn't found. Any ideas on how I would recompile libavformat to explicitly look for libavssl.co?

Comment: You mean that logcat shows that /data/data/your.package.name/lib/libssl.so was loaded?

Comment: But then, rename will not help. Does `nm -D` show `SSL_library_init` exported from your libssl?

Comment: You can see a similar problem resolved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631432/jni-onload-defined-but-not-found-on-android-4-4-2)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in FFmpegMediaPlayer.java line 614:

```
static {

    System.loadLibrary("crypto");    // loads OK
    System.loadLibrary("ssl");       // loads OK

    for (int i = 0; i < JNI_LIBRARIES.length; i++) {

        Log.d("TAG", JNI_LIBRARIES[i]);

        System.loadLibrary(JNI_LIBRARIES[i]);

    }

    native_init();

}
```