# JNI_OnLoad defined but not found on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-ndk

i had an android native lib. I've defined the JNI_OnLoad function. Everything is working with android 2.3.7, but on android 4.4.2, it says it can't find my JNI_OnLoad method. Hence, further calls to my native methods fails (obviously).

The lib (.so) is loaded and the error message appears just after the loading.

I've triple checked for typo, mismatches in methods signatures, etc... Since it works in android 2.3.7, i doubt the problem is that simple.

I've also made a test with another native lib i made and it works on both andrid versions.

I've tried to rewrite the "wrong" lib using the code of the "good" one, but it's still not working on android 4.4

I've also read the changelog of android 4.4 but didn't find anything relevant

Does anybody have an idea?

thanks

--EDIT--

Forgot to mention that a readelf on the .so shows the JNI_OnLoad:

```
192: 0000a214   252 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    8 JNI_OnLoad
```

--GOT IT--

ok, that's really weird: I just changed the name of my lib and it works. It happens that i called my lib "sync" (libsync.so). If i change this name to anything else, then it works. The lib is loaded and its JNI_OnLoad function is called.

So, be carefull: do not call an native lib "sync"

i'll post this as an answer later SO doesn't allow it right now

Comment: Indeed, there is a /system/lib/libsync.so which was probably being loaded (or re-load declined) in place of yours.