# How to loadLibrary from another package signed by the same developer in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Is it possible to load a c library put into "A" package of a developer from a package called "B" of the same developer? (package = standalone application package on Play Store)

Basically, I want to check if "com.myapps.codecArmv6" exists from "com.myapps.mainapp" and if yes, I want to use System.loadLibrary on "com.myapps.codecArmv6"'s "abc.so" from a specific class of "com.myapps.mainapp".

Is this possible?

Comment: OpenCV seems to manage this kind of trick - might be a good place to look.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, even if the two apps are not signed by the same developer. Essentially, the native libs are unpacked by installer into `/data/data/<app.package>/lib` or possibly elsewhere for Android version higher than 2.2, but with full read and execute permissions. You should use [nativeLibraryDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#nativeLibraryDir) method on 2.3 and higher to find the exact path.

Comment: Thanks! Can I find an alternative for 2.2? I want to support 2.2 and newer devices.

Comment: On 2.2, the path is fixed as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603648/how-to-get-the-path-to-the-lib-folder-for-an-installed-package