# using System.load to load a .so library from a specified path

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries

I'm trying to load a .so library from a specified "allowed" path that is:

> /data/data/my.package.name/mylibrary.so

I know that I can't just put my lib to /sdcard/ for security purpose (and this is fine).

I'm trying to load the library with:

```
System.load("/data/data/my.package.name/mylibrary.so");
```

But for some reasons I'm failing to understand, my app crash with:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/data/my.package.name/mylibrary.so" not found

Running the app in Monitor I can also read:

> avc: denied { read } for name="mylibrary.so" dev=tmpfs .......
>   tclass=file permissive=0

This looks like a SELinux issue. I've also checked the library permission in adb shell (from a root shell) and they looks okay.

I know that since Android Nougat it isn't possible to load system library, but this isn't a system lib.

Is there anything I can try?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why not just compile the library into the APK? If the answer is "because we are downloading the `.so` file", bear in mind that [this may violate Google's developer policies](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/malicious-behavior/).

Comment: @CommonsWare just for fun and learning. That's all. This is just an experimet, not something I'm doing for work ;)

Comment: Did you tried with getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir??

Comment: @E.Abdel why should I try that? i don't want to load the lib from the nativeLibraryDir

Comment: Why not? It gives you the exact native libraries path of an installed app, take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/16806802/5458344

Comment: I know that, but it is not what I'm trying to do: I want to load a lib from a custom path. Thanks for your help, but I'm not interested in the traditional way to load libs. EDIT: also the lib is not present at build time, it is dropped from the assets (after being Hex-edited on the fly).